# How to set values with react-hook-form on native html select multi

Tags: typescript, multi-select, react-hook-form

My goal is to use all native html elements in my project and I currently have working input and checkboxes using react form hook but I can't seem to get a select (multiple) to work.

Specifically, the part that doesn't work is the setting of the values with values retrieved from the server when I go to update some data (it works in every other way).

Here is the relevant code I have:

Note, Below is the actual code from my file however I have tried to remove everything that did not seem relevant to the question.  In the original code there are also functions to get the data from the backend and to handle the create and delete actions as well as some user interface stuff that again is irrelevant (i think) to this question.

The data returned from the backend is a JSON object which is an array of what I call types.  Each type has an id, name and an array of subtypes which also have ids, names and a value called 'connected' which is a boolean to determine if the type in question is connected to the subtype. The goal here is to have a table of these types and upon clicking a row in that table you can edit that particular type by changing the name and/or changing which subtypes are selected (selected types are the connected=true ones)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ErrorMessage } from '@hookform/error-message';
import { RootStateOrAny, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { updateTicketTypeAction } from '../../actions/ticketActions';

interface ttFormInputs {
  name: string;
  sub_types: [];
}

export default function Ticket() {
  const { 
    register, 
    resetField, 
    formState: { errors }, 
    handleSubmit,
    setValue
  } = useForm<ttFormInputs>();

  const types = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.root.ticket.types);


  const onToggleEdit = ((type: any) => {
    setValue('name', type.name) //this does work

    /* this doesn't work

       Note, in both of these tests, I am not even looking at the 'connected' property
       of the subtype.  I'm just trying to pre-select all of them to see if it can be
       done in any way.

    type.sub_types.map((value: any) => {
      setValue('sub_types', value.id, { shouldTouch: true })
    })
    */
   
    /* nor does this...
       
       note: stypes in this case ends up being a simple array of ids
    */
    let stypes = type.sub_types.map((value: any) => (value.id))
    setValue('sub_types', stypes, { shouldTouch: true })
    
  })

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const onUpdateTicketType = handleSubmit(async (data: ttFormInputs) => {
    dispatch(updateTicketTypeAction(data))
    resetField("name")
    resetField("sub_types")
  })


  const typeList = types.map((type: any) =>
    <tr key={ type.id }>
      <td>
        { 
          <>
            <input {...register("name", { required: "Name is required"})} />
            <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="name" />
          </>
        }
      </td>
      <td>
      { 
        <select {...register("sub_types")} multiple>
          {
            type.sub_types.map((value: any) => (
              <option key={value.id} value={value.id}>  // Note, I've also tried selected={value.connected} here, but this did not work either.
                {value.name}
              </option>
            ))
          }
        </select>
      }
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onClick={(e) => onDeleteTicketType(e, type.id)}>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="pageTitle">Ticket Configuration</h4>
      <form onSubmit={onUpdateTicketType}>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Ticket Type</th>
              <th>Sub-Types</th>
              <th>Parent-Types</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            { types && typeList }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am struggling to find any way of using native html select tags in conjunction with react-hook-form.  It seems that every example uses some sort of UI toolkit like bootstrap or something else and I am specifically trying to avoid tools like this.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and of course, after struggling with this for a day and finally posting in here, I found the answer about 10 minutes later.  Posting here so someone else doesn't need to go through the same pain.

The answer was very close to what I had already tried with my stypes variable in the example above.  The problem was that I was creating an array of numbers and the keys in the options were set to strings so they never matched.  Here is what I ended up with that worked:

```
      let stypes = type.sub_types.map((value: any) => {
        if (value.connected) return value.id.toString()
      })
      setValue('sub_types', stypes, { shouldTouch: true })
```